# Android , ndk, write willfully to a sd card file

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

After Android 4.4, the SD card needs permission to write files.
You can request to write to the SD card by StorageVolume. createAccessIntent ().
The stream is then accessed using ContentResolver().openoutputstream (file.geturi ()) to write data to the file.
How do I write data in the NDK?

```
public void startRequestPermissions(Context context) {
        Intent intent = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            if (mStorageManager != null) {
                StorageVolume volume = mStorageManager.getStorageVolume(new File(timePath));
                if (volume != null) {
                    intent = volume.createAccessIntent(null);
                }
            }
        }
        if (intent == null) {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
        }
        ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, FileBrowserConfig.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE_CODE);
    }



 public OutputStream getOutputStream(Context context, File destFile) {
        OutputStream out = null;
        try {
            DocumentFile file = getDocumentFile(destFile, false, context);
            out = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(file.getUri());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return out;
    }
```

Can write data in sd card with NDK！

Answer (score 0):

Instead of openOutputStream(), you can get a file descriptor with [openAssetFileDescriptor()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#openAssetFileDescriptor(android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal)).

Comment: Android uses C / C + + language to write files to SD card